# run bash script with elevated privileges from subprocess python multithreaded call

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, sudo

I'm programming in python on linux, and I am using multiprocessing_pool.apply_async to call a bash script using subprocess.check_output

The bash script is calling alien and rpmbuild.  The alien command needs to run as root, and because of this the rpmbuild command does also, following a root sed command to correct some rpm idiosyncrasies.

At the moment, if I want to convert several debs to rpms, I have to enter my admin password, several times.

Is there a way that I can enter my admin password only once?
ie that the script is always called with its different variables as new processes, but always elevated privileges following one password entry?
At the moment I am using pkexec to call the script with sudo being used in the script itself.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the python script as super-user, the script should not ask you a password:

```
$ sudo python -c "import os ; os.system('whoami')"
root
```

So run your thing as usual but with `sudo` before `python`. If you need to run multiple python scripts and type your password only once, type `sudo su`. You will then be root for all commands (without prepending `sudo`) until you close the terminal session.

Alternative ways to give the password:

1. You can use `sudo -A` if you want a gui prompt to appear for the password.
2. You can use `sudo -S` if you want to pass the password as stdin.

Each process has its own user, you will have to create multiple processes to have multiple users.

Comment: Better: use `sudo` only from `check_output` to run the `bash` script, not the entire Python script.

Comment: thanks, but I am hoping to keep the python qt program as a standard user, and only run sudo once.  I guess I could separate out the methods from the python class, put them in their own class and then call that as super user perhaps?

Comment: I ended up calling pkexec from subprocess